# header file for cuda event functions

Tags: visual-c++, cuda

Which header file to be included for following code snippet to measure time using cuda event mathods?

```
cudaEvent_t start,stop;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);
float Elapsed=0,Cycle;

for (int p=1; p<=MSG_NUM; p++)
{ 
    cudaEventRecord(start,0);

    add<<<R, (M+R), (M+R)* sizeof(int)>>>( d_msg, d_checkSumArray ); 

    cudaEventRecord(stop,0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaElapsedTime(&Cycle,start,stop);
    Elapsed += Cycle;
}

printf("Time = %f",Elapsed);
```

My program show following error as no header file included.

> error : identifier "cudaElapsedTime" is undefined

Can someone give the solution please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct API call is [cudaEventElapsedTime(...)](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__EVENT_1g14c387cc57ce2e328f6669854e6020a5).

Other than that your parameters look correct.

You don't need any special include headers if you are compiling with nvcc.